# En Python .como elimino para cada línea en unas series textos?

Tags: python

Tengo una series que son así :

```
0   33891876 / texto234
1   268163 / blabla68 
2   378901367 /palabras679
```

Quiero quedarme  solo con los primeros números de cada línea o sea que me devuelva esto:

```
33891876
268163
378901367
```

Estoy trabajando con una tabla que me devuelve otro programa. Separe una de las columnas q me interesaba y que la nombre como `columna=df[1]` y hago el `print` (columna) y me devuelve la serie que muestro en la pregunta.

```
0   33891876 / texto234
1   268163 / blabla68 
2   378901367 /palabras679
```

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de lo que haz hecho?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio John, realiza el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio. Para realizar preguntas asegura añadir información para que la comunidad te ayude, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: Perdón si no fui muy claro pero quise simplificar un poco , estoy trabajando con una tabla q me devuelve otro programa. Separe una de las columnas q me interesaba y q la nombre como columna=df[1] y hago el print (columna) y me devuelve la serie q mostré en la pregunta :     33891876 /texto...

Comment: @John ok etonces puedes almacenar todos los elementos de "columna" dentro de un array para tener algo como lista = ['0   33891876 / texto234', '1   268163 / blabla68 ', '2   378901367 /palabras679'] , en base a esto puedes realizar lo que deseas.

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo en Python / programación , he hecho eso , también probé con un split( para que me separe por '/' , pero no logro después quedarme solo con los primeros números..

Comment: @John agregue un ejemplo. saludos

Comment: Hola John, tu pregunta no es muy clara, si es lo que creo es extremadamente simple de hacer de forma vectorizada en una sola línea. Supongo que usas Pandas (hay otras bibliotecas en Python que manejan "dataframes" y "series" por lo que debes especificarlo), en tal caso agrega esta etiqueta a tu pregunta y explícalo de forma clara: "Tengo un DataFrame de Pandas del cual obtengo una columna de tipo str  con la siguiente estructura...., quiero quedarme con solo la parte..... etc " Es importante que te tomes tu tiempo en explicarlo todo para evitar confusiones entre gente que te quiera contestar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes almacenar los textos de cada "columna" dentro de un array y mediante un `split()` crear un array para obtener el elemento con indice 1, que seria el numero deseado,

pero primeramente debes "normalizar" tus datos para tener únicamente espacios sencillos y no un espacio triples:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para esto puedes usar un replace:

```
texto = texto.replace('   ', ' ');
```

para obtener:

```
0 33891876 / texto234
1 268163 / blabla68 
2 378901367 /palabras679
```

normalizando los datos puedes obtener mediante `split()` un array de los elementos de cada "Columna" y obtener el dato deseado, ejemplo:

```
lista = ['0   33891876 / texto234', '1   268163 / blabla68 ', '2   378901367 /palabras679']
for elemento in lista:
    elemento = elemento.replace('   ', ' '); #normaliza    
    print elemento.split(' ')[1]
```

salida:

```
33891876
268163
378901367
```

Comment: Para esto se suele utilizar el método split sin pasarle argumentos.